# ReGex in PHP, isolating between [img]

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to isolate content in-between either:

```
[img]https://URL.com[/img]
```

or

```
[img width=100]https://URL.com[/img]
```

or

```
[img *whatever*]https://URL.com[/img]
```

So that I get https://URL.com.

I tried:

```
preg_match('/\[img[^>+](.+?)\[\/img\]', $data['body'], $titlematches);
```

and

```
preg_match('/\[img](.+?)\[\/img\]/i', $data['body'], $titlematches);
```

But it didn't get the desired output.

Comment: Hope this will help you out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about php, but the regular expression should be:

```
\[img.*?\](.+?)\[\/img\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/brTleq/1)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out.

**Regex:** `\[img[^\]]*\]\K(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+`

> **1.** `\[img[^\]]*\]\K` this will match `[img` and  till `]` then `\K` reset the match
>
> **2.** `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+` this will match your `url`

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/I9BqmO/3/)

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='
[img]https://URL.com[/img]
[img width=100]https://URL.com[/img]
[img *whatever*]https://URL.com[/img]';
preg_match_all('/\[img[^\]]*\]\K(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+/', $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784749)